# How to spoof sender email address?

Tags: email, kindle

Recently I found a [web application](https://www.sendepubtokindle.com/) that can send email to my kindle `foo@kindle.com` on my behalf `myemail@gmail.com`. I am curious that how they can spoof the email sender to my gmail address without any permission. It's [Kindle policy](https://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle/email) that only email addresses from an allowed list can send email to my kindle.
Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In an email, you can change the 'from:' field to whatever you want. They simply changed the text in that field to your email address. If you would like to read more, here's the technical document describing how email should work: [RFC 2822 Internet Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822)